# Sort key-value pairs first by Value and then by Key. (similar to Radix Sort). I need to maintain the key-value relationship

Tags: java, sorting, bigdata, key-value

I'm trying to remove duplicates from key-value pairs. And sorting the Data first seems like the best way to do this. I have tuples(Both values are Integer) so the code doesn't necessarily have to work for different Objects and if it can be optimised for Integers that would be great. I would like to sort all my pairs first by Value, and then by Key(Note that I need both operations while maintaining the key-value relationship)

I'm new to Java, and I was wondering if there exist sorting methods in a Map(or any other data-structure which I can use) that would do this for me. Since the dataset I'm using is huge(>50GB), I have to save time wherever possible. I have tried simply adding all the pairs into a Set(as a concatenated string of both integers) and then taking them out, but it takes too long. I'm open to switching to external-sort algorithms if needed(I'm using 64 GB memory pc, so anything that takes more than O(n) space will be problematic)

Comment: Why do you need to sort to remove duplicate? I mean if your data can fit into the memory just put your value into a HashMap. If the map already contains a mapping for the key, the old value is simply replaced by the specified value. No duplicate Key.

Comment: If you're going to a sorting to just remove duplicates, process will be unnecessarily costly. To keep key value pairs you can simply use `java.util.HashMap`. This doesn't allow duplicate keys, but values. Every time you `put` a duplicate `key`, it will replace the previous key's `value`. So no duplicate keys. But this allows `null` key. Therefore you can consider `java.util.Hashtable` if you have risk about `null` keys. If you want if you need Key, Value both unique, you can consider about a third-party like `BiMap` from **Google Guava**.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can both sort and eliminate duplicate by storing those data into a `TreeMap`. `TreeMap` is a implementation of `Map` where  **keys in TreeMap are sorted using their natural order**. We could implement the `Comparable<Data_Type>` and override `public int compareTo(T t)` to define the sorting order.

As this is not a multikey Hash, only one key could exists in Map. So the duplicate entity will be automatically over-written.

Have a look at this link: [Sort a HashMap in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashmap-sort)